# Apache 500 error for .htaccess: "<Files not allowed here"

Tags: apache-2.4

In my Apache virtual host config file, I am using [AllowOverrideList](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverridelist).  I am using the default of `AllowOverride None` because I only want to enable specific directives in .htaccess, not groups of directives.

However, I am getting an HTTP 500 error code, with this in the error log:

```
[Tue May 09 10:16:03.271831 2017] [core:alert] [pid 16415] [client 196.52.43.51:42111] /var/www/xyz/.htaccess: <Files not allowed here
```

The first thing in the .htaccess file is a properly-formed `<Files>` section.  This shouldn't be causing a problem, because it's more of a "[meta directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html)" that's used to contain other directives.

Answer (score 1):

If `AllowOverrideList` and `AllowOverride` are both set to `None`, then .htaccess [won't be loaded at all](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#troubleshoot).  However, it turns out that there is some kind of Apache bug in which .htaccess is loaded but not processed properly -- causing errors -- if just `AllowOverrideList` but not [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is used in the main Apache config.

To fix the problem and get `<Files>` or one of the other sections to work in .htaccess, add this in addition to your `AllowOverrideList` statement in the main Apache config:

```
AllowOverride Limit
```

Your needs may vary and it's up to you to evaluate the security implications of the above.

Comment: Confirmed: if a virtualhost has `AllowOverride None` and `AllowOverrideList RewriteEngine etc…`, and .htaccess file contains `<IfModule> … </IfModule>`, it will result in an error 500, “IfModule not allowed here”. The docs say directives such as `IfModule` [are allowed in any .htaccess file, as long as overrides are enabled in the server configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/overrides.html#override-all), which is not true or very confusing, because an override is enabled in `AllowOverrideList`.  Adding `AllowOverride Limit` does solve it, so thanks for the tip!