# Apache and PHP-FPM security with mod_proxy_fcgi

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, mod-proxy, socket, mod-proxy-fcgi

I use PHP-FPM in a shared hosting configuration. Each FPM pool runs as a different user. Apache runs as www-data. Apache connects via a socket using mod_proxy_fcgi. I allow users to use .htaccess files.

How do I prevent a user from connecting to the wrong FPM pool?

The vhost looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName foo.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/foo.com/html
        <FilesMatch "\.php$">
                SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/foo-com-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
        </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

But, the foo-com user can easily override that handler from his .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/bar-com-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

This would allow him to run PHP scripts as a different user. How can I prevent that, without disallowing FileInfo overrides?

Comment: There is a similar vulnerability with the `[P]` flag of `RewriteRule`, see this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/965288/shared-hosting-apache-rewriterule-p-flag-security-concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AllowOverrideList`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverridelist) allows to further restrict .htaccess directives to the specified list.

Quote from the docs:

> When this directive is set to `None` and `AllowOverride` is set to `None`,
>   then .htaccessfiles are completely ignored. In this case, the server
>   will not even attempt to read `.htaccess` files in the filesystem.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> AllowOverride None
> AllowOverrideList Redirect RedirectMatch
> ```
>
> In the example above, only the `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` directives
>   are allowed. All others will cause an internal server error.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> AllowOverride AuthConfig
> AllowOverrideList CookieTracking CookieName
> ```
>
> In the example above, `AllowOverride` grants permission to
>   the `AuthConfig` directive grouping and `AllowOverrideList` grants
>   permission to only two directives from the `FileInfo` directive
>   grouping. All others will cause an internal server error.

Comment: I encountered a bug in Apache where setting `AllowOverride None` while specifying some directives in `AllowOverrideList …` would result in an internal server error if using any of the general directives that should be enabled if any overrides are specified. More info: https://serverfault.com/a/848981/180356